# Windows Azure Error C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, azure-storage

I'm getting this error:

> f:Erro ao processar esta solicitação.| em
>   System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveResult.HandleBatchResponse()
>   em
>   System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveResult.EndRequest()
>   em
>   System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions
>   options)  em
>   AzureTableLayer.CRUDUserEntities.ADDUSociate(UserClientEntity entity)
>   na
>   \WindowsAzureProject1\AzureTableLayer\User\CRUDUserEntities.cs:linha
>   43  em mobile.Service1.addusr(String nome, String cidade, String cpf,
>   String email, String telefone) na \Service1.svc.cs:linha 124

The method is:

```
    public string addusr(string nome, string cidade, string cpf, string email, string telefone)
    {
        try
        {
            if (nome.Length == 0)
                return "f:Preencha o campo nome.";

            if (cidade.Length == 0)
                return "f:Preencha o campo cidade.";

            if (cpf.Length == 0)
                return "f:Preencha o campo cpf.";

            if (!Valida(cpf))
                return "f:CPF Invalido.";

            if (email.Length == 0)
                return "f:Preencha o campo email.";

            Regex rg = new Regex(@"^[A-Za-z0-9](([_\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)@([A-Za-z0-9]+)(([\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)\.([A-Za-z]{2,})$");
            if (!rg.IsMatch(email))
            {
                return "f:Email Invalido";
            }

            List<UserEntity> lst = new List<UserEntity>();
            var _account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("Conn"));
            _account.CreateCloudTableClient().CreateTableIfNotExist("fiscal");
            var _context = new CRUDUserEntities(_account.TableEndpoint.ToString(), _account.Credentials);


            UserClientEntity entity = new UserClientEntity() { nome = nome, cidade = cidade, cpf = cpf, email = email, telefone = telefone };
            _context.ADDUSociate(entity);

            return "k";
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            string error =  "f:" + exc.Message + "|" + exc.StackTrace;
           // Trace.WriteLine("Erro no login: " + error , "Information");
            return error;
        }
    }
```

the ADDUSociate(where I'm getting error)

```
 public void ADDUSociate(UserClientEntity entity)
  {
      this.AddObject("UserEntities", new UserEntity { nome = entity.nome, cpf = entity.cpf, cidade = entity.cidade, email = entity.email, telefone = entity.telefone});
      this.SaveChanges();
  }
```

EDIT: the problem is in this.SaveChanges();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be an [Azure character casing issue](http://weblogs.asp.net/chanderdhall/archive/2010/07/10/dataservicerequestexception-was-unhandled-by-user-code-an-error-occurred-while-processing-this-request.aspx)? Maybe you are not using the correct casing for `"UserEntities"`.

**[UPDATE]**

This is probably because you get a reference to the `"fiscal"` table, but you want to add the entity to the `"UserEntities"` table.

There is a good sample of how you can add an entity here: [CloudTableClient.CreateTableIfNotExist Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.cloudtableclient.createtableifnotexist.aspx)

Comment: Because the parameter is a UserClientEntity and the method **ADDUSociate** is in **UserEntity** and the parameter is **UserClientEntity**